# Redirecting CreateProcess input stream to a file

Tags: c++, windows, c++11, createprocess

I'm using CreateProcess to substitute a system() call in my code. I was using:

```
system(xfoil.exe < create_results.txt");
```

Which I am substituing by this:

```
PROCESS_INFORMATION ProcessInfo; //This is what we get as an [out] parameter
STARTUPINFO StartupInfo; //This is an [in] parameter

LPCWSTR input_file = _tcsdup(TEXT(".\\create_results.txt"));

HANDLE inpfl = CreateFile(input_file, GENERIC_READ, FILE_SHARE_READ, NULL, OPEN_EXISTING, FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL, NULL);
StartupInfo.hStdInput = inpfl;

ZeroMemory(&StartupInfo, sizeof(StartupInfo));
StartupInfo.cb = sizeof StartupInfo; //Only compulsory field
LPCWSTR exe_path =_tcsdup(TEXT(".\\xfoil.exe"));

if (CreateProcess(exe_path, NULL,
    NULL, NULL, FALSE, CREATE_NEW_CONSOLE, NULL,
    NULL, &StartupInfo, &ProcessInfo))
{
    WaitForSingleObject(&ProcessInfo.hProcess, 2000);
    CloseHandle(ProcessInfo.hThread);
    CloseHandle(ProcessInfo.hProcess);
    CloseHandle(inpfl);
}

else
{
    CloseHandle(inpfl);
    std::cout << "Could not create xfoil process" << std::endl;
}
```

The reason being I need to control how long the process is allowed to run ( 2000ms in this case), however it seems that this method does not work. 
I'm redirecting the input of the process to the handle of the file I want as input (to substitute the < operator), but the process is not receiving anything. It does launch the xfoil.exe in a separate console, though.

Comment: Order matters! Where do you set `hStdInput`,  and where do you call `ZeroMemory`?

Comment: You need the call to ZeroMemory *BEFORE* you assign to hStdInput

Comment: vtc as "simple typographical error"

Comment: Damnit, that was a rookie mistake. I have changed the order, but it still doesn't work as expected.

Comment: The file *is* opened correctly?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to set file security attributes to allow handle to be inherited and startup info flag to make child process use the handle passed:

```
::STARTUPINFO startup_information{};

::SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES security_attributes
{
    sizeof(::SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES)
,   nullptr
,   TRUE // allow handle to be inherited
};

::HANDLE const inpfl{::CreateFileW(input_file, GENERIC_READ, FILE_SHARE_READ, ::std::addressof(security_attributes), OPEN_EXISTING, FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL, NULL)};
if(INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE == inpfl)
{
    auto const last_error{::GetLastError()};
    // handle error...
}

startup_information.cb = sizeof(startup_information);
startup_information.dwFlags = STARTF_USESTDHANDLES;
startup_information.hStdInput = inpfl;
```

Comment: For completeness, you should mention that there were *two* bugs in the original code: Not setting `dwFlags`, and calling `ZeroMemory` after assigning `hStdInput`.

Comment: @MartinBonner It was actually *three* bugs: supplying null pointer to security attributes makes handle not inheritable, so child process won't be able to use it. And I guess op already figured out about `ZeroMemory` anyway.

Comment: I'm trying out this solution, definitely seems like the right direction. The ZeroMemory one was a silly bug I didn't notice right away. Didn't know about the flag nor the security attributes.

Comment: It seems to work ok, I do get some file opened by another process errors, but I will figure that out without much issue, thank you. Learned a lot from this.

Comment: If the creating (parent) process is a console process, then the `STARTUPINFO` standard handles don't *have* to be used. For example, cmd.exe never uses them. In this case, the current standard handles (i.e. set via `SetStdHandle`) are inherited by a child console process regardless of whether they're inheritable or whether the child is created with inheritance. A non-console child process also inherits the handle *values* in its standard handles, but actually inheriting the handles requires them to be inheritable and creating the process with inheritance, which cmd.exe always uses.

Answer (score 0):

> ```
> PROCESS_INFORMATION ProcessInfo; //This is what we get as an [out] parameter
> STARTUPINFO StartupInfo; //This is an [in] parameter
>
> LPCWSTR input_file = _tcsdup(TEXT(".\\create_results.txt"));
>
> HANDLE inpfl = CreateFile(input_file, GENERIC_READ, FILE_SHARE_READ, NULL, OPEN_EXISTING, FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL, NULL);
> StartupInfo.hStdInput = inpfl;
> ```

What happens to StartupInfo.hStdInput after the next call?

> ```
> ZeroMemory(&StartupInfo, sizeof(StartupInfo));
> ```

Oops... hStdInput zeroed now

Doing this initially...

```
PROCESS_INFORMATION ProcessInfo = {};
STARTUPINFO StartupInfo = {};
```

... will prevent you from needing to zero anything... [see](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/zero_initialization)

Also, according to CreateProcess StartupInfo [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms686331(v=vs.85).aspx), you have to, for ***hStdInput***, set ***dwFlags*** to **STARTF_USESTDHANDLES**, else the default input is the keyboard buffer